# what is the cause of TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types when i don't have NaN value in my dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, tpot

I have a dataset which after going through it I seem not to find any `NaN` values but unfortunately, am getting `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported` when I run the code.

Link to the dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v5HQLrCuJXWLTLoaHFa5WPqakjpglEgEMGC9TLEwbjY/edit?usp=sharing

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfData = pd.read_csv('datasets/disambiguate_spam_sms.csv', encoding="latin-1")

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
training_indices, validation_indices = training_indices, testing_indices = train_test_split(sms_label,
                                                                                                stratify = sms_label,
                                                                                                train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25)

training_indices.size, validation_indices.size

from tpot import TPOTClassifier
from tpot import TPOTRegressor

tpot = TPOTClassifier(generations=5, verbosity=2)

tpot.fit(sms_data.drop('label',axis=1).loc[training_indices].values,
             sms_data.loc[training_indices,'label'].values)
```

The code below is my error code, and it keeps pointing to `sms_data.loc[training_indices,'label'].values)`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-3df5d5a2120f> in <module>()
      5 
      6 tpot.fit(sms_data.drop('label',axis=1).loc[training_indices].values,
----> 7          sms_data.loc[training_indices,'label'].values)

/home/emma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tpot/base.py in fit(self, features, target, sample_weight, groups)
    658         """
    659         self._fit_init()
--> 660         features, target = self._check_dataset(features, target, sample_weight)
    661 
    662 

/home/emma/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tpot/base.py in _check_dataset(self, features, target, sample_weight)
   1175         else:
   1176             if isinstance(features, np.ndarray):
-> 1177                 if np.any(np.isnan(features)):
   1178                     self._imputed = True
   1179             elif isinstance(features, DataFrame):

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: what is sms_label in your train_test_split code? where is it coming from?

Comment: @Hue i assigned it to the sms_data

**' sms_label = sms_data['label'].values '**

Comment: Are you sure you are using the algorithm correctly? Why are you passing only the label column in your train_test_split? Also, you are using sklearn and passing categorical data. Your message column has a lot of text, which you need to convert into numerical vector features first , before you can use machine learning.

Comment: @Hue i am passing only the label to the tran_test_split because that is the column that has the categorical data **spam/ham**

Comment: @Hue i am passing only the label to the tran_test_split because that is the column that has the categorical data **spam/ham**

Comment: and please do you have any link to a site i can learn about converting my data into numerical vector?

Answer (score 0):

First I am not sure you are using `train_test_split` correct. I believe your first `=` is misplaced.

Secondly I agree with @Humi; are you sure you are passing the right `x` and `y` values to the model? Do a

```py
print(
    sms_data.drop('label',axis=1).loc[training_indices].values,
    sms_data.loc[training_indices, 'label'].values
)
```

and verify that that is indeed the right data.

The error you are getting implies that the data being passed is of the wrong datatype, i.e. it is not numerical (?) and therefore cannot be checked by using the `isnan` function on it.